# how can I create variable in JSF to use thro' JSP tag

Tags: jsf

I am using tomahawk dataList, where I use

```
rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
```

Inside the dataList I have been using verbatim, 
where I need to retreive the rowIndex thro' JSP EL ${rowIndex}.
How can I achieve it.

Comment: a bit more context would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Anything in `<f:verbatim>` will be treated as template text. If you want to evaluate EL expressions, simply put it outside `<f:verbatim>`.

I.e. don't do

```
<f:verbatim><p><h:outputText value="#{rowIndex}" /></p></f:verbatim>
```

but rather do

```
<f:verbatim><p></f:verbatim>
    <h:outputText value="#{rowIndex}" />
<f:verbatim></p></f:verbatim>
```

True, it's ugly, but if you're using JSF 1.2 or newer, you can omit the `<f:verbatim>` anyway.

```
<p><h:outputText value="#{rowIndex}" /></p>
```

Or if you're on JSF 2.0 with Facelets, you can even use unified EL in template text:

```
<p>#{rowIndex}</p>
```